# If/else if/else error - unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to execute an `if/elseif/else` statement, but I am getting an unexpected identifier error on the second `else if`. The rest of the statement works fine. I'm very new to coding, so I apologize if this is a simple mistake.

```
if (jQuery("#question").val() === "" && (rowCount == 1)) {
    analysis_empty=1;
} else if (rowCount > 1) {
    jQuery('.analysis_empty_title').css({"line-height":"normal"});
    jQuery('.analysis_empty_title').text("Results Displayed by Date Groups");
    jQuery('#here').html(jQuery('#dategrouptable').clone().attr('id', 'tableb_copy'));
    jQuery('#tableb_copy').css({"font-style":"italic"});
    var ptr = jQuery("#tableb_copy").find("tr");    
    ptr.find("td:last").remove();
} else if ((rowCount > 1) and (jQuery("#question").val() != "" )){
    jQuery('#analquestion_empty').css({"display":"none"});//ERROR HERE
} else {
    analysis_empty=0;
    jQuery('#analquestion_empty').css({"display":"none"});
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `and` keyword you're using, since it doesn't exist in Javascript.

You should replace it to `&&`, e.g:

```
else if ((rowCount > 1) && (jQuery("#question").val() != "" )){
```

Comment: David....it has nothing to do with PHP...which only proves I need more sleep. Thank you very much Buzinas.

Comment: @DavidWeisser if my answer was useful for you, please mark it as the accepted, by clicking on the `V` right below the upvote/downvote arrows. Thanks! :)

Comment: I did Buz! Apparently, when I have more reputation...it will my +1 will increment the upvote.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
with (typeof __commandLineAPI !== 'undefined' ? __commandLineAPI : { __proto__: null }) {
if (jQuery("#question").val() === "" && (rowCount == 1)) {
    analysis_empty=1;
} else if (rowCount > 1) {
    jQuery('.analysis_empty_title').css({"line-height":"normal"});
    jQuery('.analysis_empty_title').text("Results Displayed by Date Groups");
    jQuery('#here').html(jQuery('#dategrouptable').clone().attr('id', 'tableb_copy'));
    jQuery('#tableb_copy').css({"font-style":"italic"});
    var ptr = jQuery("#tableb_copy").find("tr");    
    ptr.find("td:last").remove();
} else if ((rowCount > 1) && (jQuery("#question").val() != "" )){
    jQuery('#analquestion_empty').css({"display":"none"});//ERROR HERE
} else {
    analysis_empty=0;
    jQuery('#analquestion_empty').css({"display":"none"});
}
}
```